# Django Resolver404 error

Tags: django, python-2.7

i got this error when run python manage.py test
here the error please help me to solve this problem

```
ERROR: test_update_status_table_using_message_table_func (update_status.tests.Up
date_Status_Test)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\syuvira\update_status\tests.py", line 67, in test_update_s
tatus_table_using_message_table_func
    found = resolve('/update-status/show_post')
  File "C:\Users\USER\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 27, in re
solve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "C:\Users\USER\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 392,
 in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.urls.exceptions.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPatte
rn list> (admin:admin) ^admin/>], [<RegexURLResolver <module 'profile_page.urls'
 from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\syuvira\\profile_page\\urls.py'> (None:profile-page) ^pr
ofile-page/>], [<RegexURLResolver <module 'Add_Friend.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\USE
R\\syuvira\\Add_Friend\\urls.py'> (None:Add-Friend) ^Add-Friend/>], [<RegexURLRe
solver <module 'dashboard.urls' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\syuvira\\dashboard\\urls.
py'> (None:dashboard) ^dashboard/>], [<RegexURLResolver <module 'welcome_page.ur
ls' from 'C:\\Users\\USER\\syuvira\\welcome_page\\urls.py'> (None:welcome-page)
^welcome-page/>], [<RegexURLPattern index ^$>]], 'path': 'update-status/show_pos
t'}
```

here my tests.py

```
def test_update_status_using_index_func(self):

    found = resolve('/update-status/')
    self.assertEqual(found.func, index)
```

Comment: Please try to paste error message as text instead of putting screenshot. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: what is the url declaration for `/update-status/` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) that [resolve](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.resolve) function is triggering inside of your test code.

> If the URL does not resolve, the function raises a Resolver404 exception (a subclass of Http404).

```
def test_update_status_using_index_func(self):
   try:
       found = resolve('/update-status/')
       self.assertEqual(found.func, index)
   except Resolver404:
       self.fail("Couldn't not resolve URL')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to test it:

```py
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from django.urls import resolve, Resolver404

from myproject import settings

class TestError404(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.debug = settings.DEBUG
        settings.DEBUG = False

    def tearDown(self):
        settings.DEBUG = self.debug

    def test_404(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Resolver404):
            resolve('/foo/')
```